# How to determine which rows were touched by a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that has a handful of dependencies throughout a database, which include other procedures that, in-turn, deal with other tables. Each procedure is only selecting data from these tables, no deletes, updates, or inserts are made. The tables this procedure is pulling from are reasonably large (millions of records), and the procedure is generally only selecting a small subset from each of those tables (10s to 100s of records).

I would like to know, for each table the stored procedure selects from, specifically which records were selected. (This data is being extracted and used to generate test scenarios for our quality support group.)

I have looked into using profiler, audits, and extended events so far. All of these seem to get close, in that they tell me that a certain select statement was executed against each table. This would be good enough, however, there is a hangup.

Most often, the where clauses of these select statements contain variables that were defined somewhere in a calling procedure. Profiler, audits, and extended events don't seem to show me the select statement in its fully prepared state (with variables replaced with values).

I would like to see either a specific list of records returned, or the select statement used to return the data with variables replaced with concrete values.

Is there a way of accomplishing this?

---

**Edit with some addition info:**

I have profiler set to show and time sproc statements start or tsql statements start. This shows in the trace each statement that includes a SET or SELECT to give a variable a value. For instance, I will see a line like `DECLARE @Foo BIT = 1`, and later I will see a statement `SELECT Flar FROM Grib WHERE Narg = @Foo`. However, what I really want to see later is `SELECT Flar FROM Grib WHERE Narg = 1`

Comment: I think the best you can do is capture the call of the sproc with the parameters used, then you have to do the digging to find affected rows in the tables yourself by deconstructing the query.

Comment: CAn you give me an example of what you are seeing from profiler? In general if you use parameters to astored proc they show up in profielr. So are you determining the values internally to the proc through some sort of querying?

Comment: See my edit with additional info above.

Comment: I should note this is in SQL Server 2012. I added that tag to the post.

Comment: Create additional table with selected row id-s and add query in SP which fills this table before actual `SELECT`. Unfortunately there is no `selected` virtual table similar to `inserted` and `deleted` for use in triggers.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was afraid of. Was hoping there was some sort of magic out there in extended events that would do what i'm looking for, but I think your suggestion @i486 is probably the only real solution.